# Trying to open an image file from the network with a link in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I've built a simple report in Spotfire that consists of two tables. In one of the tables I've got a column that stores a partial network drive location that I would like for the user to be able to click on and the image open.

The partial value that is store looks like this.....

```
Test/BA/qmanged/Acme Truck Line, Inc. MSA.pdf
```

I've tried changing the column properties to a link and populate the rest of the network path.....

```
file:///q:/Test/Folder/FileShareRepository/{$}
```

but when I click on the value in the table nothing happens.

Comment: will your user be accessing the analysis via the thick client or the web client?

Comment: Are you using webplayer? What Spotfire version are yo uusing?

Comment: The users will be accessing from the web client.

We are using build version 7.0.1.10

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the files to open from the webplayer (and not have images rendered from them),  you need to enable additional URI and file extensions. In the spotfire client, navigate to Tools->Administration manager, and then select preferences.   In the preferences tab, select the Everyone group, then edit. Under Application->ApplicationPreferences, set Allow Additional File Extensions and Allow Additional Uri Schemes  to true.